# RASPBERRY PI WEBSERVER PHP MAIL PROBLEMS

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, php

Welcome to my first stackoverflow question :/

Today I bought myself my first domain on strato.de.
I created on my raspberrypi a webserver to host my website, added my domain to it - so i can connect to my webserver over my domain.

My website got a contact form which takes data and a message and sends a mail to my email.

I installed php on my raspberry but I dont know why the form does not work.
The emails are never arriving.

**MY HTML FILE:**

```
<form action="./mail_handler.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="p pb-3"><strong>Feel free to contact me </strong></div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                          <div class="col">
                            <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                  class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"
                                placeholder="Firstname" required="required" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                          <div class="col">
                            <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                  class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"
                                placeholder="Lastname" required="required" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                          <div class="col">
                            <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                  class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail"
                                required="required" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                          <div class="col">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"
                                required="required"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Send</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
```

**MY PHP FILE**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "contact@mymail.de"; // Empfägner Adresse
$from = $_POST['email']; // Absender Adresse
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
// $phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = "PORTFOLIO";

$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . "\n" . $from .  " schrieb folgendes:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header('Location: ./contact_success.html');
}?>
```

[phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2USkY.jpg)

I tried so much I dont know what I can do, maybe someone can help me.
If you need more infos just hit me up

Answer (score 0):

STOP!!!  The code that you have implemented has severe security vulnerabilities.  You have implemented an open relay.   You use user input in in email headers without any sort of sanity checks, validation, or escaping.  All user input MUST be checked before it is used in the email.

For example, if somebody includes a new line in the from email address the submit, they can add extra arbitrary headers.

```
me@example.com
CC: spamrecepient@example.com
```

If you have this contact form accessible to the world, it will soon be found by spammers and used as an open relay.

As to why it isn't working, there are a couple possibilities.  The obvious one is that you use a "From" header for the `$to` email address but then never use that `$header2` when sending the email.

Another possibility is that the `mail()` function isn't configured to send email properly.  On linux based OSes, PHP `mail()` calls the Linux system for sending mail called `sendmail`.   It sounds like you haven't configured and tested that system.   Here is a guide: [Enable Outgoing Mail on Raspberry Pi | Unix etc.](http://unixetc.co.uk/2014/11/04/enable-outgoing-mail-on-raspberry-pi/)

Rather than write your own contact form, I would suggest that you use an existing one.   I have written a [free, open source contact form](https://ostermiller.org/contactform/) that you can use.   You'd still have to configure sendmail, but it validates all user input properly and is easily configurable.

Comment: Thanks for the info with the security issues. I didnt had time to build them in right now, but ive got some questions:

1. The weird thing is - when i hosted the website on the webspace of strato.de everything worked fine. And there also didnt used the $header2 .
2. I changed the mail function to sendmail and after that the website isnt even responding.

Comment: Most hosting companies set up sendmail for you.  It should be fine for your script to call the PHP mail function because the documentation for it says that it calls sendmail behind the scenes.

Comment: But Im hosting it on a raspberry pi which is attached to my router - so from my home

Comment: Yes so on your raspberry pi you still have to configure sendmail but you can still use the PHP mail function.

Comment: but if i can use php mail why is it not working :(

Comment: Have you tested sendmail?  php mail won't work until you configure and test sendmail.

Comment: https://ibb.co/nc0JVM6 
I think i setted sendmail up - im kinda new in all this stuff so pls dont wonder if i dont get everything you say.

i rode something about smtp server do i have to install it seperatly on my pi too?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set up your own SMTP server.   I usually configure `sendmail` to route my mail through my domain's SMTP server logging in as my user with my password.   I'm not sure how to do that one Pi.  I use Ubuntu with Exim4 providing sendmail.  See [How do I configure exim4 to send mail through a password protected ssl smtp mail server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167043/how-do-i-configure-exim4-to-send-mail-through-a-password-protected-ssl-smtp-mail)